# Can we make different folders for prod and non-prod in multistage YAML Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, yaml-cpp

We have around 13 prod and 13 non-prod environments in multistage YAML pipeline, due to this the performance is very slow. Can we keep prod and non-prod in a separate folder, so that while deploying we can run ci/cd independently.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Without details how you build your pipelines it could be difficult to say you exact answer, but yes of course that you can and probably even should not to deploy to all envs. I'm not sure what you mean by saying folder. But with conditions you can get fain grained control over which and where you deploy your code.

Comment: Also confused about the meaning of different folders. Please check whether my answer can help you. Let me know if I have any misunderstanding about your question

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know whether my anwser helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we keep prod and non-prod in a separate folder, so that while deploying we can run ci/cd independently.

If you need to run CI/CD independently, you can split your pipelines into build pipelines and release pipelines.

Build pipelines automate test and build for your project. Release pipelines delivery automatically deploy and test code in multiple stages to help drive quality.

If your issue is that the application is deployed to all environments, then as Krzysztof Madej commented, you can modify your pipeline to deploy to one or more of them.